# Show App Store app page in app

Tags: ios, app-store

There are some apps (like the free version of Cut the Rope) that present the App Store page of other apps directly in the app (probably using a modal view controller).
How do I implement this in my own app?

Example from Cut the Rope:
[image]

Comment: What you are talking about is the SKStoreProductViewController class.

Comment: call your app url/itunes url directly

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SKStoreProductViewController` for this, check out [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/SKStoreProductViewController.html) for more detail

```
if ([SKStoreProductViewController class]) {
    NSString *yourAppID = @"";//Give your app id here
    NSDictionary *appParameters = @{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier :yourAppID};
    SKStoreProductViewController *productViewController = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
    [productViewController setDelegate:self];
    [productViewController loadProductWithParameters:appParameters completionBlock:nil];
    [self presentViewController:productViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: As `SKStoreProductViewController.h` says, `SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier`'s value is "iTunes Store item identifier (NSNumber) of the product"; it's NOT a string. If writing in Swift, String value causes failure.

Answer (score 1):

One can implement a App Store page of any application within their own app by using the SKStoreProductViewController class.

```
NSString *strURL = @"" //Keep the App store URL here.
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]floatValue] >= 6.0)
    {
        SKStoreProductViewController *storeProductViewController = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];

        NSRange range = [strURL rangeOfString:@"/id"];
        NSRange rangeID = {range.location + 3, 9};

        NSString *strAppID = [strURL substringWithRange:rangeID];
        NSLog(@"appid = %@", strAppID);

        // Configure View Controller
        [storeProductViewController setDelegate:self];
        [storeProductViewController loadProductWithParameters:@{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : strAppID}
                                              completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
                                                  if (error) {
                                                      NSLog(@"Error %@ with User Info %@.", error, [error userInfo]);
                                                  } else {

                                                  }
                                              }];
        // Present Store Product View Controller
        [self presentViewController:storeProductViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

The above code also extracts the app ID from the URL.

You can read about it in the [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/SKStoreProductViewController.html).